# Sources on the Consequences of insulting

Tags: karma, pali-canon

I recently encounted a situation where some comic fans in my country gathered up and had a Comic Con and it was worth their effort on making their own costumes. They have spend a lot of their time and dedication to represent their fictional characters.

After the event was over I saw certain low minded individuals have used certain pictures of the cosplayers and have insulted them in vrry bad ways (memes and some relate to nudity) and it went viral. Some of those cosplayers were pretty depressed after that and all. And the other organizers and them defended them and now it has gone viral all over the world and everyone else is supporting.

This is the scenario I encountered. My question is what are the karmic and other type of consequences of insulting a person's character according to the Pali Canon? Can I have references to them?

-Metta

Answer (score 1):

I think the most famous sutta is [Akkosa Sutta: Insult (SN 7.2)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn07/sn07.002.than.html).

Answer (score 0):

Akila, as for the possible reason of insulting:

> "There is the case where a woman or man is envious. He/she envies, begrudges, & broods about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence, salutations, & veneration. Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in the plane of deprivation... If instead he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is not influential wherever reborn. This is the way leading to not being influential: to be envious, to envy, begrudge, & brood about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence, salutations, & veneration.
>
> "But then there is the case where a woman or man is not envious. He/she does not envy, begrudge, or brood about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence, salutations, or veneration. Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in a good destination... If instead he/she comes to the human state, he/she is influential wherever reborn. This is the way leading to being influential: not to be envious; not to envy, begrudge, or brood about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence, salutations, or veneration.
>
> [Cula-kammavibhanga Sutta: The Shorter Analysis of Action](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than_en.html)

As for the insulting itself, the ill-will harm, not with words and signs, such may the reason why people are often harmed, most ugly, the outsiders in groups and sociaty.

It's good to be reminded mainly to simply avoid such things by one self and good to remind that being insulted has having insulted as cause, when, and where ever it was, to do not fall in certain finily judgement, seeing being hurting each other. That's their ways they seek and think on Comics, what then attracting people by their fighting and insulting each others, do attract Comic fans.

One liking to watch and be joyful entertained by watching fighting, insulting, stories of winning and game, will be part of the movie which is in so far different, that the current hero is ever changing, does not stay with oneself. Watching shows, movies, such parades and Events... it all forces either greed, aversion, delusion grow in one.

Therefore the abstaining from entertainment and shows is praised by the wise and all Arahats and those following them did, do and will do likewise, Akila.

[*Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant to be used for commercial purpose or other wordily gains but intended for Nibbana: so to be given without bounds to things like that*)